# Regex, not statement

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, negation

Heyho,

I have the regex

```
([ ;(\{\}),\[\'\"]?)(_[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]*)([ =;\/*\-+\]\"\'\}\{,]?)
```

to match every occurrence of

```
_var
```

Problem is that it also matches strings like

```
test_var
```

I tried to add a new matching group negating any word character but it didn't worked properly.

Can someone figure out what I have to do to not match strings like var_var?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Perhaps, `\b_[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+\b` is what you need.

Comment: I tried it out in regex101, works fine but I don't get any matches in my python script. `regex = re.compile('([ ;(\{\}),\[\'\"]?)(\b_[a-zA-Z\_\-0-9]+\b)([ =;\/*\-+\]\"\'\}\{,]?)')
        found = regex.findall(line)
        found = list(set(found))` Anything I missed?

Comment: Ok, fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following "fix":

```
([[ ;(){},'"]?)(\b_[a-zA-Z_0-9-]*\b)([] =;/*+"'{},-]?)
                ^                 ^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS7cY2/1)

The word boundary `\b` is an anchor that asserts the position between a word and a non-word boundary. That means your `_var` will never match if preceded with a letter, a digit, or a  . Also, I removed overescaping inside the character classes in the optional capturing groups. Note the so-called "smart placement" of hyphens and square brackets that for a Python regex might be not that important, but is still a best practice in writing regexes. Also, in Python regex you don't need to escape `/` since there are no regex delimiters there.

And one more hint: without `u` modifier, `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so you can write the regex as

```
([[ ;(){},'"]?)(\b_[\w-]*\b)([] =;/*+"'{},-]?)
```

See [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/zS7cY2/2).

And an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/RgPcmM) (note the use of `r'...'`):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([[ ;(){},\'"]?)(\b_[\w-]*\b)([] =;/*+"\'{},-]?)')
test_str = "Some text _var and  test_var"
print (re.findall(p, test_str))
```

Comment: Like already mentioned it works really fine. Thanks for the explanation, now I also understand what you gave to me. Thanks!